# How to calculate Fisher criterion weights?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, discriminant-analysis

I am studying pattern recognition and machine learning, and I ran into the following question.

> Consider a two-class classification problem with equal prior class probability $$P(D_1)=P(D_2)= \frac{1}{2}$$
>
> and the distribution of instances in each classes given by
>
> $$ p(x|D_1)= {\cal N} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\0 \end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \right),$$
>
> $$ p(x|D_2)= {\cal N} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 4  \\ 4 \end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right).$$
>
> How to calculate Fisher criterion weights?

**Update 2:** The calculated weight provided by my book is:
$W=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-4}{3}   \\ \frac{-2}{9}  \end{bmatrix}$.

**Update 3:** As hinted by @xeon, I understand that I should determine the projection line for the Fisher’s discriminant.

**Update 4:** Let $W$ be the direction of the projection line, then the Fisher linear discriminant method finds that the best $W$ is the one for which the criterion function is maximized. The remaining challenge is how can we get numerically  $W$ vector?

Comment: Your first distribution is undefined. In particular the second variate of the pair has a degenerate distribution with 0 variance, but does have a positive covariance with the first variate, which is impossible.

Comment: @owensmartin do u have any idea, how these values calculated?

Comment: What is the definition of the Fisher criterion weight?

Comment: I means Fisher’s linear discriminant is given by the vector w which maximizes... it's noted on every material like as http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Learning/Kernelpapers/00788121.pdf on p. 2.   is it okey @xeon ?

Comment: Hint: What will be the boundary between the two classes? Linear, polynomial, something else?

Comment: more hint will be required !‌ I think the solution that mentioned by my book is wrong ! @xeon thanks

Comment: Ok, how do you interpret the weight vector? Can you draw it? What will it define?

Comment: I‌ Try to draw it and update my question after chat with xeon.

Comment: The fisher LDA can be solved by generalized eigen value also. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121181/generalized-rayleigh-quotient

Comment: @dksahuji my problem is via numerical calculation, would you please give me an example?

Comment: @dksahuji I put bounty on this question, because this is interesting question, please share your idea on the following answer.

Comment: @nini ok. I will do so.

Answer (score 11):

Following the paper you linked to [(Mika et al., 1999)](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Learning/Kernelpapers/00788121.pdf), we have to find the $\mathbf{w}$ which maximizes the so called [generalized Rayleigh quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Generalizations),

$$\frac{\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{S}_B \mathbf{w}}{\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{S}_W \mathbf{w}},$$

where for means $\mathbf{m}_1, \mathbf{m}_2$ and covariances $\mathbf{C}_1, \mathbf{C}_2$,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}_B &= (\mathbf{m}_1 - \mathbf{m}_2)(\mathbf{m}_1 - \mathbf{m}_2)^\top, &
\mathbf{S}_W &= \mathbf{C}_1 + \mathbf{C}_2.
\end{align}

The solution can be found by solving the [generalized eigenvalue problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem)
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}_B\mathbf{w} = \lambda \mathbf{S}_W\mathbf{w},
\end{align}
by first computing the eigenvalues $\lambda$ by solving
\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{S}_B - \lambda \mathbf{S}_W) = 0
\end{align}
and then solving for the eigenvector $\mathbf{w}$. In your case,
$$\mathbf{S}_B - \lambda \mathbf{S}_W = 
\begin{pmatrix}16 - 3\lambda & 16 \\ 16 & 16 - 2\lambda\end{pmatrix}.$$
The [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#2.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A02_matrices) of this 2x2 matrix can be computed by hand.

The eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue maximizes the Rayleigh quotient. Instead of doing the calculations by hand, I solved the generalized eigenvalue problem in Python using `scipy.linalg.eig` and got
$$w_1 \approx 0.5547, w_2 \approx 0.8321,$$
which is different from the solution you found in your book. Below I plotted the optimal hyperplane of the weight vector I found (black) and the hyerplane of the weight vector found in your book (red).

$\hskip1in$[image]

Comment: +1. Down-right entry in the matrix should probably read $16-2\lambda$.

Comment: Perhaps we should report unit vector $w$ since the hyperplane is defined by direction, not magnitude.

Comment: This example is very interesting. The both lines separate the two classes but one of them is "better" from learning theory point of view.

Comment: Both lines separate the two classes. One of them will more likely predict new data point which will come from one of the distributions. The red one will more likely misclassify it compared to the second one. More rigorous justification can be found with SVM, this is how it selects the separating hyperplane - the one with largest margin.

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang: Can you tell us which book you are referring to?

Comment: Fisher Criterion is detailed at section 5-2-3 on https://books.google.com/books?id=gb79v56894oC&pg=PT255&lpg=PT255&dq=find+fisher+criterion+weight+solution&source=bl&ots=dR-H3Dq6v9&sig=88yctbn3gHVfWVQsO112Tmfrhq0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jNsfVemcC8reUbeTgdgK&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=find%20fisher%20criterion%20weight%20solution&f=false

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang: the two vectors are different even when normalized to unit norm, otherwise the hyperplanes would be the same. The Fisher criterion linked to by nini would give equivalent results to the ones I got (since the criterion only differs by a constant factor).

Comment: @Lucas  maybe the  result in question is close to xeon comments, "Perhaps we should report unit vector w since the hyperplane is defined by direction, not magnitude. "  isn't it ?

Comment: Oh !!! challenging question, I recommend all to see page 2 on http://dml.ir/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/SPR-S12-M-Sol.pdf

Comment: I agree with @Lucas's answer theoretically and I also used the closed form solution for two class LDA $w = {S_W}^{-1}(m1-m2)$ and got $[0.5547; 0.8321]$ as w. Which is correct as far as I understand. I can discuss how we get this closed form solution.

Comment: I have added an alternate solution as an answer which is very easy to compute by hand for this problem. Hope this helps!!! :)

Also the black boundary might be correct as LDA has class information and hence it is not surprising the we get a nice separator. In the specific plot, we can easily see that separator and vector (m1-m2) looks like perpendicular and I am not at all surprised as variance are not too skewed and are nice almost spherical and spherical.  And maybe popoulation too are comparable with almost no extreme outliers.

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang, the solution in your book is **not** a unit vector.

Comment: @Lucas Thanks. would you please add another picture for W=[-2/3 -2/3] and W=[-4/3 -2/3] and W=[-2 -3] with three different color to see the boundary? Thanks. I set bounty to you for nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbf{SOLUTION 1:}$

Following Duda et al. (Pattern CLassification) which has an alternate solution to @lucas and in this case gives very easy to compute solution by hand. (Hope this alternate solution helps!! :))

In two class LDA the objective is:

$\frac{w^TS_Bw}{w^TS_Ww}$ which just means that increase the between class variance and decrease the within class variance.

where $S_B = (m_1-m_2)(m_1-m_2)^T$ and $S_W = S_1 + S_2$, here  $S_1,S_2$ are covariance matrix and $m_1,m_2$ are means of class 1 and 2 respectively.

The solution of this generalized raleigh quotient is a generalized eigen value probem.

$S_Bw = \lambda S_Ww \rightarrow {S_W}^{-1}S_Bw = \lambda w $

The above formulation has a closed form solution. $S_B$ is a rank 1 matrix with basis $m_1-m_2$ so $w \propto {S_W}^{-1}(m1-m2)$ which can be normlizd to get the answer.

I just calculated the $w$ and got [0.5547;0.8321].

${S_W}^{-1}(m1-m2) = {(S_1 + S_2)}^{-1}(m1 - m2) = {(\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 + \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix})}^{-1}(\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 
 \end{bmatrix}
  - \begin{bmatrix}
  4 \\
  4 
 \end{bmatrix}
 )
 ={(\begin{bmatrix}
  1/3 & 0 \\
  0 & 1/2
 \end{bmatrix})}(\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 
 \end{bmatrix}
  - \begin{bmatrix}
  4 \\
  4 
 \end{bmatrix}
 )
 = \begin{bmatrix}
  -1.3333 \\
  -2.0000 
 \end{bmatrix} \propto 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0.5547 \\
  0.8321 
 \end{bmatrix} $

Ref: Pattern Classification by Duda, Hart, Stork

$\mathbf{SOLUTION 2:}$

Alternatively, it can be solved by finding eigen vector to the generalized eigen value problem. 
$S_Bw = \lambda S_Ww$

A polynomial in lambda can be formed by $determinant(S_B - \lambda S_W)$ and the solutions to that polynomial will be the eigen value for $S_Bw = \lambda S_Ww$.
Now lets say you got a set of eigen values $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n,$ as roots of the polynomial. 
Now substitute $\lambda = \lambda_i, i \in \{1,2,..,n\}$ and get the corresponding eigen vector as solution to the linear system of equations $S_Bw_i = \lambda_i S_Ww_i$. By doing this for each i you can get a set of vectors $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and it is a set of eigen vectors as solutions.

$determinant(S_B - \lambda S_W) = \begin{bmatrix}
  16 - 3\lambda & 16 \\
  16 & 16 - 2\lambda
 \end{bmatrix} =6\lambda^2 - 80\lambda$, So eigen values are roots to polynomial $6\lambda^2 - 80\lambda$.

So $\lambda= $ 0 and 40/3 are the two solutions.
For LDA, eigen vector corresponding to highest eigen value is the solution.

Solution to system of equation $(S_B - \lambda_i S_W)w_i = 0$ and $\lambda_i = 40/3$

which turns out to be $\begin{bmatrix}
  16 - 3\lambda & 16 \\
  16 & 16 - 2\lambda
 \end{bmatrix}w_i \propto \begin{bmatrix}
  -72 & 48 \\
  48 & -32 \end{bmatrix}w_i = 0$

Solution to the above system of equation is $\begin{bmatrix}
  -0.5547 \\
  -0.8321 \end{bmatrix} \propto \begin{bmatrix}
  0.5547 \\
  0.8321 \end{bmatrix}$ which is same as previous solution.

Alternatively, we can say that $\begin{bmatrix}
  0.5547 \\
  0.8321 \end{bmatrix}$ lies in the null space of $\begin{bmatrix}
  -72 & 48 \\
  48 & -32 \end{bmatrix}$.

For two class LDA, eigen vector with highest eigen value is the solution. In general, for C class LDA, the first C - 1 eigen vectors to highest C - 1 eigen values constitute the solution.

This video explains how to compute eigen vectors for simple eigen value problem. ( https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/eigen_everything/v/linear-algebra-finding-eigenvectors-and-eigenspaces-example )

Following is an example.
http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen2/eigen2.html

Multi-class LDA:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA

Calculating Null Space of a matrix:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/null_column_space/v/null-space-2-calculating-the-null-space-of-a-matrix

Comment: Nice answer, you means answer of book is wrong!! Okey?

Comment: I believe that this answer is correct and if your book defines $S_W$ and $S_B$ differently then see what you get with those definitions.

Comment: I misunderstand, so the book answer mentioned in my question is wrong? Yes?

Comment: I am just saying with the definitions I have used, my answer is correct. I dont want to claim more than that because I have not seen your book.

Comment: -1.33 is equal to -4/3 but the second element is differ. Maybe book report unit vector w? Isn't right? Thanks so much

Comment: I am not sure about that or it could be a typo.

Comment: please complete solution 2 to reach value of W to bounty it

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang, the solution in your book is **not** a unit vector.

Comment: @amoeba thanks for hearing from you. What do u think? You means my book has a typo in second element?!

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang: The solution in your book is wrong. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Dr.Hoshang solution 2 example has also been added to the answer if you are interested. Hope it helps and you have got your answer.